# Procedure too large error from transferring large number of named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import a large set of data from one Excel workbook to another. I cannot use queries or any other data connection. The thing is, columns (number and order) change over time.

So I defined names for 206 columns of the source workbook in VBA (`Dim xyz_Source As Long`). Then I search for the locations of those 206 columns (`xyz_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("xyz", Source.Range, 0)` and create a range (`Source.Range(Cells(2, xyz_Source), Cells(LastRow, xyz_Source`).

Afterwards I do the same for the target file (`Dim xyz_Target As Long & xyz_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("xyz", Target.Range, 0)`) and put it togehter as a `range`.

Eventually, I copy them individually and paste them into the target file (also individually), one at a time.

That basically creates an entire book of code for this simple procedure. And Excel throughs a "procedure too large" back at me.

Do you know any smart way of shortening the code / looping through / outsourcing parts to other modules; i.e. make it more intelligent?

Any advice is really appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's an example/extract of my code:

```
Dim Column_Name_1_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_2_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_3_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_4_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_5_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_6_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_7_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_8_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_9_Source As Long
Dim Column_Name_10_Source As Long

Column_Name_1_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 1", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_2_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 2", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_3_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 3", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_4_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 4", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_5_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 5", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_6_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 6", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_7_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 7", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_8_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 8", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_9_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 9", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)
Column_Name_10_Source = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 10", Source.Range("10:10"), 0)

Dim Column_Name_1_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_2_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_3_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_4_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_5_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_6_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_7_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_8_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_9_Target As Long
Dim Column_Name_10_Target As Long

Column_Name_1_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 1", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_2_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 2", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_3_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 3", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_4_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 4", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_5_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 5", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_6_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 6", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_7_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 7", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_8_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 8", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_9_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 9", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
Column_Name_10_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column Name 10", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)

‘Column_Name_1:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_1_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_1_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_1_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_1_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_2:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_2_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_2_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_2_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_2_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_3:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_3_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_3_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_3_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_3_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_4:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_4_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_4_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_4_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_4_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_5:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_5_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_5_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_5_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_5_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_6:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_6_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_6_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_6_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_6_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_7:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_7_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_7_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_7_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_7_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_8:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_8_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_8_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_8_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_8_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_9:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_9_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_9_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_9_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_9_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
‘Column_Name_10:
Source.Range(Cells(11, Column_Name_10_Source), Cells(Lastrow_Source, Column_Name_10_Source)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Target.Range(Cells(10, Column_Name_10_Target), Cells(Lastrow_Ziel, Column_Name_10_Target)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

New code with loop (still with errors):

```
Dim colname_Target As Variant
Dim colnum_Target As Variant
Dim colnum_Source As Variant
Dim i_Target As Long
Dim Unique_ID_Target As Long

Unique_ID_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Unique Identifier", Target.Range("9:9"), 0)
colname_Target = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Target.Range(Cells(9, 1).Address, Cells(9, Unique_ID_Target - 1).Address).Value2))

ReDim colnum_Target(Unique_ID_Target)
ReDim colnum_Source(Unique_ID_Target)

For i_Target = LBound(colname_Target) To UBound(colname_Target) Step 1
    colnum_Target(i_Target) = Target.Rows(9).Find(What:=colname_Target(i_Target), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
Next i_Target

For i_Target = LBound(colname_Target) To UBound(colname_Target) Step 1
    colnum_Source(i_Target) = Source.Rows(10).Find(What:=colname_Target(i_Target), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
Next i_Target
```

Comment: Can you show your code and not just snippets of it? Also, rather than using VBA for this, can you not just use **"INDEX+MATCH"** in your "MASTER" file?

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks for your quick responds. No, Index-Match is not an option (for various reasons). Like I said, the code is pretty massiv, but I'll add an extract/example.

Comment: Have you tried creating an array of all possible column names, then use that to create an array of column locations, where you can use the column locations for the appropriate information?  Should help with allocation.

Comment: Hi Cyril, how would that work? Could you provide an example based on the above code? I can't imagine it shortens the code a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @ReneHanschke In trying to use the code you've got, the first error I got was on the line for *Unique_ID_Target*, since you're using a defined range, do you need *Target*?  Not sure what you're having people select to run this; similar throughout your code.  A couple things with your colname_target array... your data will ALWAYS be a multi-dimensional array, so you will need to have appropriate array calls, e.g., colname_target(i_target,1).  [ran out of space, using 2 comments]

Comment: You can utilize the data in the single row, though you cannot use lbound/ubound as those are equivalent to rows.  For i = 1 to Unique_ID_Target will work, and then you utilize your array like colname_target(1,i_target).

Comment: Thanks again a million, @Cyril! Re. naming w/ [...] Target and Source: Since I got columns and parameters for target and source files, I just add this string for better reading of the code. Unique_ID_Target is the last column in the target file, until which I need the locations of the columns. So I search all column names in the target file until Unique_ID, create an array for their names and another one for their location. I don't get, why the second array doesn't work for the source file. Any idea? Also, I'm doing 2x transpose to utilize the array w/ i only (not (i,1)). [see next comment]

Comment: So basically I should be able to use the name array of the target, to search for the locations in the source file, creating a source location array. Once both arrays are set, I will need to copy from range_source to target. I'm still having troubles to come up with this part. If you can help, I'd be very greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few changes to @Cyril 's code, this one works perfectly:

```
Dim i As Long, destcolname As Variant, srccolnum As Variant, lrd As Long, lcd As Long, lrs As Long, r As Long, c As Long

With Sheets("destination")
    lrd = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lcd = .cells(11,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    destcolname = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, lcd)).Value)

End With
With Sheets("Source")
    ReDim srccolnum(lcd, 1)
    For i = 1 To lcd
    On Error Resume Next
        srccolnum(i, 1) = .Rows(10).Find(What:=destcolname(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    Next i
End With

With Sheets("destination")
    lrs = Sheets("Source").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 11 To lrs
        lrd = Sheets("destination").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 1 To lcd
            Sheets("destination").Cells(lrd + 1, c).Value = Sheets("Source").Cells(r, srccolnum(c, 1)).Value
        Next c
    Next r
End With
```

Thanks again, @Cyril!

Answer (score -1):

Example of my comment (not tested):

```
dim colname as variant, colnum as variant, i as long
colname = array("colA","colB","colC")
redim colnum(3)
for i = lbound(colname) to ubound(colname) step 1
    on error goto moo
    colnum(i) = Rows(11).Find(What:=colname(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
next i
for i = lbound(colnum) to ubound(colnum) step 1
    if colnum(i) > 0 then
        'use the data with cells(row,col)
    end if
next i
'on error
moo:
    colnum(i) = 0
```

---

**Edit1:** Will add some info on utilization...

If you have a desired output, use that when defining your array of column headers, so when you loop through that (second loop), you can do soemthing like:

```
destination.cells(lastrow+1,i).value = source.cells(31,colnum(i)).value
```

Using value=value versus copy/paste helps with speed, as well.

---

**Edit2:**

Will try using your code and updating a few things, if it helps

```
Dim colname_Target As Variant
Dim colnum_Target As Variant
Dim colnum_Source As Variant
Dim i_Target As Long
Dim Unique_ID_Target As Long

Unique_ID_Target = Application.Match("Unique Identifier", Target.Range("9:9"), 0) - 1 'added -1 so you don't have to put it in other places
'array for column names
colname_Target = Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(9, Unique_ID_Target)).Value2

'sets each array equivalent size to colname...   
ReDim colnum_Target(Unique_ID_Target)
ReDim colnum_Source(Unique_ID_Target)

'this loop populates the array colnum_target, using the values of colname_target    
For i_Target = LBound(colname_Target) To UBound(colname_Target) Step 1
    colnum_Target(i_Target) = Rows(9).Find(What:=colname_Target(i_Target), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
Next i_Target

'this loop populates the array colnum_source, using the values of colname_target          
For i_Target = LBound(colname_Target) To UBound(colname_Target) Step 1
    colnum_Source(i_Target) = Source.Rows(10).Find(What:=colname_Target(i_Target), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
Next i_Target
```

One thing to say after reviewing your code... try to use Dest or something other than Target, as Target is defined in VBA and is used regularly for Change_Events.  I take it you are using variables such as Target = Sheets("Destination") and Source = Sheets("Source")?  That is at least my inference.  My comment about using Target was based on the use of VBA's "Target", sorry about not catching the Source reference for a sheet/book until now.

I will say that I am confused why you have a second array for the colname/colnum.  The proposed intention was to use the destination order of columns to create an array of columns for the same header names as they appear on the source document, in case they are a different order.  As such, you would then be able to loop from start to end (column 1 to last column) on the destination sheet and input data from the source, such that:

```
dest.cells(lastrowdest+1,i).value = source.cells(r,colnum(i)).value
i = i+1
```

After you have your array, you can utilize the array data such that (this uses your 2 arrays, though can be done with only the 1 array for the source data):

```
For r = 11 to lrs 'lrs is last row source, starting on 11, as it looks like your headers are in 10
    lrd = Dest.Cells(Dest.Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).row
    Dest.Cells(lrd+1,colnum_target(j)).value = Source.Cells(r,colnum_source(j))
    j = j+1
Next r
```

---

**Edit3:**

Will try to shorten up my thoughts into one bit of code using your data (but will use Dest for destination, rather than Target, because of naming conventions):

```
dim i as long, destcolname as variant, srccolnum as variant, lrd as long, lcd as long, lrs as long, r as long, c as long
with sheets("destination")
    lrd = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    lcd = .cells(11,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    destcolname = .range(.cells(11,1),.cells(11,lcd)).value
end with
with sheets("source")
    redim srccolnum(1,lcd)
    for i = 1 to lcd 
        srccolnum(1,i) = .rows(9).Find(What:=destcolname(1,i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    next i
    lrs = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    for r = 10 to lrs
        lrd = sheets("destination").cells(sheets("destination").rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
        for c = 1 to lcd
            sheets("destination").cells(lrd+1,c).value = .cells(r,srccolnum(1,c)).value
        next c
    next r
end with
```

Something like that should work?  didn't test, just did that off the head

Comment: Looks great, thanks! I'll give it a try and get back to asap.

Comment: Hi Cyril,I tried to make it work with first progress. (The first "from i" should rather be a "for i" and the "on error" statement causes an error. I'm now using a range in the target file to get the column names and create an array, incl. column numbers. However, when I'm also trying to get the column names from the source file, I receive the error message 91 (object variable or with block variable not set). Any idea? I add my code in my initial question. I also don't get the second loop yet. After having the locations of the source and the target column, how can I copy them (as range)?

Comment: @ReneHanschke sorry for the mistype in the code; yes, that's *For i*, and the on error now utilizes goto.  About to check your update...

Comment: Thanks @Cyril, I'll feedack to you asap.

Comment: @ReneHanschke Sorry for the change... did Edit3 to give a more complete understanding of my intentions